# MS Excel - Data Validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, validation

I am looking for formula i can use in the Data Validation tool in Excel.

There is a type of field i want to apply rules to:

1. Numeric & Symbols only (no alpha)

I am at a complete loss, tried several google searches to no avail. Numeric only, or Text only seems to be easy, but removing just 1 character type and leaving the other 2 seems tricky.

I'd like to do this through the Excel Data Validation tool, rather than any sort of add-on.

Can anyone help?

Is there perhaps a way I can state `=AND(ISNUMBER(A1)` and then list all the characters to allow? `!@#$%^&*-()'";:/?.><,` ?

**Attempt 1**There has to be a better way than the below, (Also Data validation in excel wont let me enter a formula long enough to include even just the lowercase Alpha characters)

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND("a",N14)),ISERROR(FIND("b",N14)),ISERROR(F‌​IND("c",N14)),ISERRO‌​R(FIND("d",N14)),ISE‌​RROR(FIND("e",N14)),‌​ISERROR(FIND("f",N14‌​)),ISERROR(FIND("g",‌​N14)),ISERROR(FIND("‌​h",N14)),ISERROR(FIN‌​D("i",N14)),ISERROR(‌​FIND("j",N14)),ISERR‌​OR(FIND("k",N14)),IS‌​ERROR(FIND("l",N14))‌​,ISERROR(FIND("m",N1‌​4)),ISERROR(FIND("n"‌​,N14)),ISERROR(FIND(‌​"o",N14)),ISERROR(FI‌​ND("p",N14)),ISERROR‌​(FIND("q",N14)),ISER‌​ROR(FIND("r",N14)),I‌​SERROR(FIND("s",N14)‌​))
```

**Attempt 2**
The below does work for both upper and lower case Alpha characters, but only if a single character is entered e.g. 'A'     as soon as you enter 'AB' the solution fails

=AND(N14<>"a",N14<>"b",N14<>"c",N14<>"d",N14<>"e",N14<>"f",N14<>"g",N14<>"h",N14<>"i",N14<>"j",N14<>"k",N14<>"l",N14<>"m",N14<>"n",N14<>"o",N14<>"p",N14<>"q",N14<>"r",N14<>"s",N14<>"t",N14<>"u",N14<>"v",N14<>"w",N14<>"x",N14<>"y",N14<>"z")

**Update:**
To clarify, i need the user to be able to enter Max 12 characters. e.g. '-$4000.00' (Im comfortable adding in the LEN(N14)<13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following formula in Data validation, Custom, Formula:
`=OR(AND(CODE(A1)>90,CODE(A1)<97),CODE(A1)<65,CODE(A1)>122,A1="")`
It will allow numbers and punctuation but not a-z, A-Z
If or returns True
For more than one character in cell use:

```
=AND(OR(AND(CODE(A1)>90,CODE(H1)<97),CODE(A1)<65,CODE(A1)>122),NOT(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),A1)))))
```

whatever is written first character or in the middle it will detect it
Because code will test only the first character

**Update**
To be more simple just use:
`=NOT(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),A1))))`

Comment: Hi Sam - That works if the first character to be entered is an Alpha, but entering a number/symbol and then alpha e.g. '4cheese' does not result in an error :(

Comment: I guess OP wanted strings to be larger than just one character.